# Referencing an ASP.NET xproj from a csproj

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, csproj

I'm using one of those new "Class Library (NuGet Package)" templates from Visual Studio, and I want to create an xUnit test library for it.

The problem is, when I create a new .csproj library and try to reference the .xproj package, Visual Studio says `"The reference to XXXX could not be resolved."`

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: are you creating the .csproj library manually or are you using the designer to `Add-> New Item-> C# Library`.. if you are doing it manually it sound like from first glance a `namespace issue` can you show the class definition of the library..? or you could be missing a `using xxxx` meaning the name of that class in the header section

Comment: @MethodMan Nope,  using the designer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you using dnx451 or dotnet framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SideWaffle](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a16c2d07-b2e1-4a25-87d9-194f04e7a698) template pack VS extension to create xUnit project templates using the new xproj project type. It is developed by a Microsoft developer and is the recommended approach at the moment (It is what they use in ASP.NET 5).