# How do I reference project.json project from a winforms csproj project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I would like to add a project.json library into my solution, so I could debug through the library code. My main project is csproj.

For example I get latest from [Rx.NET githab](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) and add [System.Reactive.Core](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Core/project.json) to the solution. I reference System.Reactive.Core from the main winforms csproj.

When I try to use anything from the System.Reactive.Core, Visual Studio cannot compile the code saying that `"The reference to XXXX could not be resolved."` similar to what is said [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356023/referencing-an-asp-net-xproj-from-a-csproj).

The reference to the library is shown in the References node of the project, but that does not help.

What is the best way to resolve this, short of creating a new csproj, and adding all the files from System.Reactive.Core project to it and referencing *that*?

**Update**

This is not a duplicate of [How to Reference .xproj into .csproj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369279/how-to-reference-xproj-into-csproj). It's specific to referencing from a WinFroms project. The accepted answer suggest converting the project to xproj: it is unclear how to do that for WinForms project and if it is possible at all, and also the other answer claims that xproj is a dead-end. Referencing NuGet package is not suitable for the stated goal of source code debugging. Looking for practical solutions.

Comment: adding a project to a solution is different from referencing one project from another. you can't add a reference to `System.Reactive.Core` to the solution, you add it to a project. if there is an output file (dll?) from your project.json project, you could maybe reference that from your winforms project and then use a decompiler (jetbrains dotPeek) to view the decompilation.